# How to know whether the Bash read time-outed(-t) or no input(enter)

Tags: bash, shell

I need to compare whether my input is null(timeout) or <kbd>enter</kbd>...

```
read -t3 ANS
if [ "$ANS" == "" ]; then 
    echo "input is null"
fi
```

when press <kbd>enter</kbd> or wait timeout, both `$ANS` are always ""(null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `$?` after `read` - it will be `1` on timeout, else `0`.